# ListItem lost its content after applying alignItems: 'center' to the parent view

Tags: react-native

I only applied `alignItems: 'center'` to the View, and lost all content of ListItems.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because we are setting alignment center of parent view. Don't set alignment center of parent view. Create another child view and set alignment center of that.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
      {/*... QR code image */
    </View>
    <View>
      {/*... list view*/}
    </View>
</View>
```

Or you can also set `alignSelf` instance of `alignItems`

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}>
      {/*... QR code image */
    </View>
    <View>
      {/*... list view*/}
    </View>
</View>
```

`alignSelf` set position for only that element. It will not reflect other element which is child of same parent.